# How do I see all available methods on a svc file?

Tags: wcf

As a contrast with a asmx file, how can I get in the visual service page that shows the available methods on the service?

> http://soweb.adwiza.com/person.asmx

Versus

> http://soweb7.adwiza.com/remote/person.svc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WCF does not have the list of operations page.  The information *is* available by looking at the raw WSDL http://soweb7.adwiza.com/remote/person.svc?WSDL.

If you want a friendlier way to see that information as well as the ability to invoke the service (which the old ASMX page gave for simple types) then you can use the [WCF Test Client (WcfTestClient.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx).

It will show you all of that information:

[image: WcfTestClient]